# WINAPI MoveWindow trick

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Once I've been given a task to create application that doesn't have a regular window shown to user. All the navigation was held from taskbar, something like a Spotify app -> in order to listen to a playlist you do not need a window.

[image]

Everything was displayed in this small area. I tried many ways to achieve that but finally I simply invoked `MoveWindow(hWnd, -10000, -100000, width, height, ...)` and it worked! But something popped in my head -> is this solution even safe? It seems odd to me to draw things behind the screen. I initially thought that Windows doesn't even bother and simply ignores drawing calls for this window. But somehow I can see update in application on this small preview window above taskbar. I suspect that it might be actually redrawn behind the screen. Then is the following true -> Windows redraws window but doesn't send a request to the graphics driver to show application on screen? It seems quite logical in spite of efficiency.

Comment: Have you considered a setup, where (-10000, -100000) is actually **on** screen? Not the typical setup today, but with ever increasing pixel densities your solution will turn into a liability at some point. Anyway, to answer your question: DWM does use the graphics hardware to render window content to DirectX offscreen surfaces, used for the thumbnail API, or Windows 7's Flip 3D feature. There are other reasons besides a window being visible to the user for Windows to issue redraw requests.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah, you got me. but this point actually doesn't matter -> I can set it to 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)  + 1000 and it will never show up on screen I guess... But monitor drivers won't get notified about change outside the screen, will they?

Comment: Actually, Windows NT moves minimized windows to (-32000, -32000) to get them out of the way.  Windows 95 and 98 used large, positive coordinates to do the same trick.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041028-00/?p=37453

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yeah but many 'old Microsoft's tricks' turned out to be unsafe and resulted in major bugs.

Comment: @greenshade:  This particular one is still done today, so I don't think it was too unsafe.

Comment: Is that window still "regular" visible (WS_VISIBLE) application window? If yes then a user could alt-tab to your application, couldn't he?

Comment: @KonstantinL of course he can. But he is unable it see it onscreen.

Comment: @greenshade It is sometimes uncomfortable for a user to lose focus in such a way.